# am I missing something in testing my API route?

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404

I have implemented a basic code for my backend. And I want to test my API route however every time I try to test it on postman or insomnia I always get and error 404 Not found. However my server is running since I am getting a message to my console confirming that. It is just my route is not working when I make a post request to Postman and Insomnia Here is my code for auth route.

the file path is `C:\Users\user\subsApp\backend\routes\auth.route.js`

```js
import express from "express";
import { registerUser } from "../controllers/auth.controller.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", registerUser)

export default router;
```

and this is my auth.controller.js

```js
import NewUser from "../models/NewUser.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import catchAsyncErrors from "../utils/catchAsyncErrors.js";

export const registerUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    username,
    email,
    citizenship,
    academicQualification,
    password,
    confirmPassword,
  } = req.body;

  try {
    // Check if the user already exists based on the email
    const existingUser = await NewUser.findOne({ email });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, message: "User already exists" });
    }

    // Check if the password and confirmPassword match
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, message: "Passwords do not match" });
    }

    // Hash the password before saving the user
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Create a new user instance
    const newUser = new NewUser({
      username,
      email,
      citizenship,
      academicQualification,
      password: hashedPassword, // Save the hashed password
    });

    // Save the new user to the database
    await newUser.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: "User created Succesfully!" });
    // Send token for authentication
    //sendToken(newUser, 201, res); // Sends token in the response
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Server Error" });
  }
});
```

I wanna know what might be the reason why I am getting an error 404 message. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried doing an HTTP POST request on insomia like this
`localhost:5000/register` and then I tried
`localhost:5000/auth/register`

and both are giving me

> 404 error NOT FOUND

this is my server.js btw

```
    *// server.js
    import express from 'express';
    import cors from 'cors'
    import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
    import authRoute from './routes/auth.route.js'
    import userRoutes from './routes/user.route.js'
    import connectDB from './database/db.js';
    
    const server = express();
    
    const corsOptions = {
      origin: 'http://localhost:5173', 
      methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
      allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
    };
    
    
    server.use(cors(corsOptions));
    server.use(bodyParser.json());
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    
    // Connect to MongoDB
    connectDB()
    .then(() => console.log("Database connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    
    //middleware
    server.use("/register", authRoute);
    server.use("/login", userRoutes);
    
    server.use("/", userRoutes);
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });*
```

Comment: How are you registering the `router` from `auth.route.js` with your main `app`?

Comment: I added the main server.js in the original post above. Hopefully, it can help you guide me

Comment: You've registered your `authRoute` under the `/login` path so the URL would be `http://localhost:5000/login/register`. **This can be closed as a typo**

Comment: wait sorry, it was supposed to be under the /login is supposed to be under userRoutes and the /register under the authRoute

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Your `auth.route.js` registers the `/register` path in its router. That router is then added to your app with `app.use('/login', authRoute)` so the final path is `/login/register`. If that's not the URL you want, then fix up your paths

Comment: I edited the server.js as per my intentions to point out what I was trying to say

Comment: Ok, so now the final path is `/register/register`. Hopefully that clears up how Express routes are constructed. Please see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html. Perhaps you want `app.use('/auth', authRoute)` for a final path of `/auth/register`